# Making Web config connection strings more generic

Tags: security, web-config, asp.net-web-api2

I need to deploy my MVC (Web api2.0) applications into QA then after passing, into production.  My apps access several SQL databases.  I cannot set security=integrated in either QA or Production so I set it to False but need to include the UID and Passwords in the web config files.  I know I am missing something here but how can I make process more secure and more generic so that I do not need to recompile between Dev - QA - Production and do not need to place the credentials in the web config?

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt them, copy the encryption results in your config, then decrypt.  Here's one way to do that:

[Encrypt and decrypt a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string)